# Прибавление по классам единиц, десятков, сотен и т.д

Tags: java

Столкнулся с проблемой написания калькулятора. У меня есть переменная one.
В переменной one хранится первое обрабатываемое число. Мне надо чтобы при нажатие кнопки, добавлялась десяток, сотня и т.д.
Тоесть нажал кнопку 2 и вместо значения 1 - получаешь 12.
Нажал кнопку 1 на экране загорелось - 1, потом нажал кнопку два - на экране теперь 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос(как добавлять символы к имеющейся строке), то вам нужно хранить значение числа в переменной типа String. Когда вам потребуется добавить в конец строки числа(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), то вам нужно выполнить следующую операцию:

```
one+="ваше число".
```

Например:

```
String one="";
one+="1";
one+="2";
System.out.println(one);//выведется "12"
```

А если вам понадобится преобразовать это число в тип integer, то вам следует выполнить следующую операцию:

```
int oneInteger = Integer.parseInt(one);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите именно в числах решать, то сначала умножайте на 10, потом прибавляйте набранную цифру. Либо собирайте число целиком в как строку, потом парсите из из String в Int/Float